# Hover Effect Multiple Child Elements

Tags: css, hover, effect

Is it possible to keep an element hover effect when hovering over a sibling element? I created a jfiddle to demonstrate. I'm trying to keep the `.child-menu-img` 100% opacity while hovering over the H3 text. I figured out that when hovering over the `.child-menu` div I can affect the h3 using `.child-menu-item:hover>h3` but I can't find a way to keep the hover effect working while hovering over the h3. Hope this makes sense! I'm wondering if this will require jQuery but so far, my searches haven't found any solution (javascript or pure CSS). Or maybe I need to modify my markup in order to get this working. I'm so lost!

Thanks for any help!

http://jsfiddle.net/inhouse/rfexypLz/

Comment: Is this what you want? http://jsfiddle.net/koala_dev/rfexypLz/9/

Comment: @koala_dev that's exactly what I was looking for! Thanks a ton! The missing CSS was `.child-menu-item:hover a>img`

Comment: No problem, but keep in mind this is a Q&A style site so it is always best to add an answer instead of updating the question with the solution. I have added mine below, please consider marking it as accepted so as to let the community know your issue is now solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you need to use `.child-menu-item:hover` as the base for all your hover state styles:

```
.child-menu-item:hover a>img {
    opacity: 1;
    filter:alpha(opacity=100);
}
.child-menu-item:hover>h3 {
    background:white;
}
.child-menu-item:hover h3 a {
    opacity: 1;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

**[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/koala_dev/rfexypLz/9/)**